# Avoiding CSS overriding bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using css to alter how several images look. One thing that I always had issues with before however was that images would get cut when screen size is made smaller. Below is an example of one class I made.

```
.headerimage {
  height: 400px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../images/metal.jpg);
}
```

I've recently started using bootstrap and noticed an img-responsive class that allows for images to be dynamically altered to fit on any webpage regardless of the size.

Using the img-responsive class however does not work when I use any of my css image classes. I've tried the following but my css classes always override bootstrap's img-responsive class.

```
<div class="img-responsive headerimage "></div>
```

Is there a method to make my css classes for images not override bootstrap's img-responsive or would I need to use HTML to call my images?

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/metal.jpg" height="400" width="900" />
```

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly set width and height on an image along with using .img-responsive? .img-responsive won't work with fixed size, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I thought `img-responsive` was **only** applied to images...isn't that the point?

Comment: 'img-responsive' for images, not for backgrounds.

Comment: Say for instance an image is 1024x768 and I want it more so to be a rectangular image. Is there no way to set dimensions to make it rectangular and then have the .img-responsive alter the image whenever page size is too small but keeping it as a rectangle?

Comment: @Paulie_D All `img-responsive` does is basically set `max-width: 100%`. You can apply it to any element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I think what you're looking for is `background-size`:

```
.headerimage {
    max-width: 900px;
    background: url(...);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

That way your background image will always fill your div, which in turn adjusts to the container up to its `max-width` (which you can probably omit as well if you have some sort of a container that defines your pages width).

Comment: One thing I don't really understand that well, whenever using max-width or max-height, none of my background images are able to load. Is there a reason for this? Up until now I've avoided using max- simply because of this.

Comment: @Valrok, is there anything in the div besides the background-image? If not, then the height of the div will be zero, maybe that's the problem?